# Wordpress, magic fields and post types in menu's

Tags: wordpress

I used magic fields a while back and I don't remember having any issues getting my post types to display in my menus.

From what I remember and have been able to research online all I need to do is the following:

1. Create a new Post type in Magic fields
2. In the advanced Options make sure "Show in nav menus" is selected
3. Add a new custom post
4. Browse to Appearence > Menu's
5. Select my main navigation menu
6. On the left hand side select the Post type

However When I get to #5 it's not displaying on the left as I remember.

I created a new dev site on my local machine, installed Wordpress 3.4 and  Magic field 2.2.1, Then I tried to make a post type and add it to the menu but this again did not display for me anywhere in the menu options.

I just can't seem to find it.

I've even been through the database entry for the new post type just to check the JSON (At least I'm pretty damn sure it's JSON) and It seems to be setting the show in navs option correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to set the top panel, called "screen options". You must select your custom post type to be visible in on the left side menu.